# Commenting out a property in a Property file

Tags: java, configuration-files

I am using java to manipulate a property file. I have a requirement like I have to comment out a property value before updating and add that property with new value. Like

> path=c:\

after I update it should be like

> #path=c:\
>   path=c:\my_folder

Is it possible to achieve this ? Below is the code I use for editing property file.

```
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        String currentDirectary=System.getProperty("testDir");
        String path=currentDirectary+"/test.Properties";
        FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(path,true);
        prop.setProperty("path","c:\\my_folder");
        prop.store(out, null);
```

Comment: You cannot save comments using the standard library.  You would need to code this yourself.  A simpler approach might be to rename the old file so you can compare the changes made with `diff` or the like.

Comment: Did you try to comment not a property, but value?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, standard `Properties` class does not handle line by line comments but only a initial comment through the `Properties#store` method. So if you want this functionality you have to code it on your own. In this [post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/544562/java/java/save-properties-file-affecting-existing) you can find an alternate implementation that can be easily adapted to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following 'kind of a hack':  Just build a `comments` containing the old values and pass it to the store method, the comments will be written at the stat of the file, thus you will not have a commented old value immediately followed by the new value.

Here some sample code:

```
@Test
public void propCom() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("some.properties");
    p.load(fr);
    fr.close();

    StringBuilder comments = new StringBuilder("Some properties\n");

    String oldValue = p.getProperty("path");
    comments.append("path=");
    if(oldValue != null) {
        comments.append(oldValue);
    }
    comments.append("\n");

    p.setProperty("path", "c:\\some\\other\\dir");

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("some.properties");
    p.store(fw, comments.toString());
    fw.close();
}
```

Starting with this content

```
path=c:\\
```

The updated properties file will look like this

```
#Some properties
#path=c:\
#
#Thu May 09 00:41:49 CEST 2013
path=c\:\\some\\other\\dir
```